# Display space betweeen 2 textfields

Tags: html, css

if you see below image or visit [link1](http://stylebaby.com/customer/account/login/) , below text "ALREADY REGISTERED" we can see 2 textboxes with good amount space between them.

[image]

but if visit [link2](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/customer/account/login/) than there is no space between them, please help me to display space between those textfields.

[image]

```
.input-box {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is there in both the links, I guess adding a `margin-bottom:10px` to the input tag should solve the issue.

Comment: @J19 in mozilla firefox, [link](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/customer/account/login/) is displaying like this : http://prnt.sc/ccdyhg

Comment: Check the updated answer. I tested it in both Chrome & FireFox. And please don't forget to approve and vote up the answer, if it solves your issue. Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both links are the same. but anyway. you do something like this.

```
.input-box {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @cssbeginner remove the following css in input-box
    `float: left;`
    `adding-bottom: 20px;`
    `width: 100%;`

Comment: @cssbeginner if you remove those css I mention, that will also fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

use 
 tag between two input text boxes

```
<input type="text" name="email">
<br>
<input type="text" name="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
.input-box {
   padding-bottom: 20px; 
   display: table; 
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` from `.input-box` and it's work fine.

```
.input-box{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your css like this,

```
.input-box {
    float: none;
    /* padding-bottom: 20px; */
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also this if want fix the position of `* Required` text

```
.fieldset p.required {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: See the updated answer. Tested on both FireFox & Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this class on `li` inner `div` `.input-box`

your html like blow

```
<ul class="form-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="">
                                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Your email" title="Email Address" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" id="email" value="" name="login[username]" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" title="Password" id="pass" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" name="login[password]">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="f-left" href="http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/customer/account/forgotpassword/">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="control remember-me-box">
        <div class="input-box">
        <input type="checkbox" title="Remember Me" checked="checked" id="remember_meG1nd66Tg4Y" class="checkbox" name="persistent_remember_me">
    </div>
    <label for="remember_meG1nd66Tg4Y">Remember Me</label>
    <a href="#" class="link-tip">What's this?</a>
</li>
                    </ul>
```